# IntelliJ Idea issue while compiling - Object mapper class not found

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compilation

Spring Boot App - Running on intelliJ.
Every time I take update from another branch and merge in to my branch i get error at the following line...even if it is already compiled.

```
objectMapper.readValue(request......
```

The readValue function is not found, then eventually somehow after sometime it works, but it sucks lot of time, is there any way to do fast indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Use command maven idea:idea, this resolved my issue.